# Not able to focus on element in grid without clicking using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a Grid in Shadow-Dom, my scenario is to get all the rows of the grid, grid is dynamic and i need to scroll. However when i am changing my focus on grid i am clicking on first row of grid this will open the new page. I there any way to bring focus on to grid without clicking so that i can scroll to the end?

**Already used**

```
ClickElement(element);
action.MoveToElement(GetElement(element)).SendKeys(pagingKey).Perform();
```

Comment: You can do it with js script

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll into view**

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: \"center\", inline: \"center\"});", webElement);
```